# First row of div's affected by stepdown

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a site that is having some major "div stepdown". The site is [The Vanity Group](http://thevanitygroup.com) and the issue is showing up in the 'Press' Section.

As you can see, the very first row is staggered and I've attempted to change the display. I've tried working on the float. I've tried working on the baseline. Nothing seems to be affecting the display of these divs.

My inclination is that the issue is within the .information_details .information_black classes because I've recently changed those. It's all been to no avail as I can not seem to find out what is causing the issue.

Thank you for any time and assistance anyone can provide.

Comment: Sounds like a `display:inline-block` issue but you haven't set `vertical-align:top`. However without code, it;s hard to help.

Comment: It's because you have page breaks in between each content block. Remove the `<br>`s and it will resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `<br>` you have between each `<div class="four columns">` to resolve the issue. There's no reason to put breaks there.

Comment: It worked! It's built in Wordpress and Wordpress was sneakily adding those <br>. Thanks!